# my coding in constructing a hailstone sequence results in endless circulation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to construct a hailstone sequence.Why can't it end the circulation and output the results?

```
def hailstone(n):
    """
    print the hailstone sequence starting at n and return its length
    """
    hail=[n]
    while n>0:
        if n%2==0:
            n=n/2
            hail.append(n)
            #n=n/2
        elif n%2==1:
            n=n*3+1
            hail.append(n)
            #n=n*3+1
    return hail

something like this:
 >>> a = hailstone(10)
    10
    5
    16
    8
    4
    2
    1
    >>> a
    7
```

Comment: I would suggest adding some print statements into each of your if checks right before your append call. That might allow you to see what it happening. It's not clear if your "something like this" is the actual output or the output you would like to get?

Answer (score -2):

def hailstone(n):
    """
    print the hailstone sequence starting at n and return its length

> > > a = hailstone(10)
> > >           10
> > >           5
> > >           16
> > >           8
> > >           4
> > >           2
> > >           1
> > >       a
> > >           7
> > >           """
> > >           count=1
> > >           while n>=1:
> > >               if n==1:
> > >                   print(n)
> > >                   break
> > >               elif n%2==0:
> > >                   print(n)
> > >                   count+=1
> > >                   n=n//2
> > >               else:
> > >                   print(n)
> > >                   count+=1
> > >                   n=3*n+1
> > >           return count

a=hailstone(10)
a
b=hailstone(27)
b

## remember to set break